# adb повреждает копируемый архив

Tags: java, android, zip, android-adb

Программа на Android устройстве пакует файлы из /files/ в архив. Необходимо извлекать архив с помощью adb (другая программа на ПК должна будет запустить bat файл с командой для adb). Если извлечь архив с помощью файлового менеджера Android Studio, то с архивом всё будет в порядке, если это делать командой для adb:

```
adb.exe -e shell "run-as com.example.ivan.fgc cat /data/data/com.example.ivan.fgc/files/archive.zip" > archive.zip
```

то один из файлов архива всегда повреждён ("ошибка контрольной суммы" или "неожиданный конец архива").
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные причины такого поведения или посоветуйте пути обхода данной проблемы.

Код создания архива:

```
/**
     * Упаковывает все файлы директории files и дополняет ими архив archive.zip
     *
     * @param context Контекст
     * @throws IOException Исключение записи/чтения
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    public void packIntoArchive(Context context) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<File> files = getFiles(new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath()));
        if (!files.isEmpty()) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/archive.zip", true);
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (File file : files) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getPath().substring(context.getFilesDir().getPath().length() + 1));
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
                zipOut.closeEntry();
                fis.close();
                file.delete();
            }

            zipOut.close();
            fos.close();

            removeFilesNDirs(new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Удалить всё кроме архивов из папки
     *
     * @param dir Директория
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    private void removeFilesNDirs(File dir) {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                removeFilesNDirs(file);
            }
            if (!file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получить все файлы из директории (за исключением архивов)
     *
     * @param dir Папка
     * @return Массив файлов
     */
    private ArrayList<File> getFiles(File dir) {
        ArrayList<File> filesNDirs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<File> iterator = filesNDirs.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            File file = iterator.next();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                files.addAll(getFiles(file));
                iterator.remove();
            } else {
                if (!file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
                    files.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

**UPD:** Открыл оба архива, внутри показывает, что файлы обоих архивов одинаковы по размеру, как и суммарный их размер, а в их поле CRC32 одинаковые значения. Однако повреждённый архив всегда больше на некоторое количество байт (отличия были на 56, 42, 14, 12). Поле Свойства->Архив у "здорового" в порядке, у второго везде "0" или "неизвестно"[image: Один и тот же архив, извлечённый через device file explorer (слева) и adb (справа)]

**UPD:** Частично обошли проблему. На реальном планшете сработало так:

```
adb.exe -d shell "run-as com.example.ivan.fgc cp /data/data/com.example.ivan.fgc/files/archive.zip"  /sdcard/archive.zip
adb.exe pull /sdcard/archive.zip
```

Виртуальное устройство на команду cp отзывается "permission denied"

Comment: а посмотри что в битом через редактор. может там "нет такого файла" или что-то вроде того

Comment: @eri какой именно редактор? Архиватором открыть, если правильно понимаю?
Целый архив, полученный через device file explorer (встроенный в Android studio) можно открыть, просмотреть структуру и распаковать любым архиватором, всё будет в порядке, все файлы будут на месте. Если архив достать через adb, то все файлы так же лежат на своих местах, однако открыть и/или распаковать можно все, кроме одного.